# MySQL, detect row value change on sorted index

Tags: mysql, onchange

MySQL newbie.

I have a huge database (some 33 millions rows).
Every X seconds a new row is added.

DATE_TIME is stored as primary key. 
A progressive INDEX (unsigned int) is recorded. It grows only.
Of course DATE_TIME and INDEX are already sorted.

The full structure is:

```
DATE_TIME, INDEX, SOME_VAL1, SOME_VAL2
```

I need to find only the lines where INDEX changes.
What is the fastest query to obtain this?

Comment: Do you mean your `INDEX` contains values like 1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4..?

Comment: Yes. It can be repeated and it is always growing.

Comment: please explain what you men with "index changes"

Comment: INDEX is either unchanged between successive rows or bigger. 
I can be 123 at 11:00:00, 123 at 11:00:05, 124 at 11:00:10, 126 at 11:00:15, 126 at 11:00:20...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select FIRST(date_time), index, FIRST(some_val1), FIRST(some_val2)
from YOURTABLE
group by index
```

Comment: Thank you @Danilo. 
Using FIRST I have a Syntax Error both from command line and using HeidiSql. Working with MariaDB really.  
Without it it works perfectly.

Comment: It looks like the GROUP BY action is slowing it down a lot. 
I was expecting some "ultrafast" standard command that would manage a case like this. Isn't it so normal to request a value break query?

Comment: @AlexPoca, `FIRST` is not a valid keyword in MySQL (it's probably for MS SQL-Server). It works without any [aggregation function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) because MySQL (or MariaDB) picks the first row for each `INDEX`. But there is no guaranty that this behavior won't change in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
select *
from mytable t
where t.DATE_TIME = (
    select min(DATE_TIME)
    from mytable t1
    where t1.INDEX = t.INDEX
)
```

Or

```sql
select t2.*
from (
    select min(t1.DATE_TIME) as DATE_TIME
    from mytable t1
    group by t1.INDEX
) t1
join mytable t2 
    on t2.DATE_TIME = t1.DATE_TIME
```

The second query might be faster. You need an index on the column `INDEX`.

Comment: Thank you @paul.
I will check the speed. Alas I cannot add an index the database to test the second solution.

Comment: @AlexPoca. without that index any solution will be slow. In best case you will need to scan the entire table.

Comment: +1 Yes, it is slower indeed compared to Danilo's solution. It looks like I will need to reorganize the database to improve its efficiency. Thank you @Paul.